Blender material list is broken
I was working on blender 4.1.1 and suddenly the material list was missing, I restarted Blender and opened a new file but the problem persists. Anyone knows how can I bring it back? It's very difficult to work like this. Thanks in advance.


Please share a minimal file representing the error on https://blend-exchange.com/ , to see if we can reproduce the problem. I'm afraid this looks as if it could be a bug, in which case we are not equipped to deal with it on BSE, and, instead, you will have to make a report.

I could upload the file but when I open the same file on my laptop the material list works fine

OK, this does look like a bug, in however Blender is playing, in  the environment on the failing machine.. It  should be reported .. ( See Header > Help ).  Check your graphics drivers / OS are up to date, first. I'm very sorry,  we can't help here, and your post will probably have to close.

@RobinBetts I thought at first, maybe it's not a bug and it is possible that the material list looks empty while it is just accidentally filtered: material filter but then I realized there is no filter available in the material list in the screenshot as it seems... so it is probably really a bug.

Thanks @GordonBrinkmann  I don't like to stomp on posts without checking carefully. Will  just await response from marcod, if any .. holding off for a bit.

I get this problem when cycles plugin is deactivated, are you filtering your addons in 3d panel using (N shortcut) Tool tab>workspace>Filter addons ?

@cscholl I finally found the problem, for some reason when I disabled the Flow addon the material tab got hidden also, I had to reinstall the addon it for it to work, this is not a permanent solution but at least I found a workaround for the time being. Thank you all for the help.
